# Replace character and the characters before and after text with pattern

Tags: vim

I need to replace a character with a pattern but the characters before the selected character also need to be replaced, using the search and replace function.

For instance: `.` has to be replace with `1/2`, so `hugo.ignatz` becomes `hug1/2gnatz`.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Hi. Could you edit your post and add any relevant code you have tried?  Maybe showing what you have tried with the search and replace function?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I am completely new to Vim, and I've been googling for a command for about an hour now, couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right, do you want this?

```
:%s#.[.].#1/2#g
```

this will replace `x.y` by `1/2`

Comment: Yes! Thank you :)
Could you explain to me what each part of the command does?
I'm completely new to vim, so you also resolved my issue with the / in 1/2. Didn't know you could use # too. I'm guessing in the .[.]. part, the dots outside the brackets are used to tell vim to replace the characters next to the pattern inside the brackets too.

Comment: it's regex. `.`  means all single char, `[.]` means literal dot. Read `:h :s` in vim for `:s` command. So it replaces `anySingleChar+dot+anySingleChar` by `1/2`. If you don't know what is `[....]`, I suggest you reading some tutorial of Regular Expression. @Streamline